# Execute controller asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a controller within another controller in the HTML file. I want to execute both controllers asynchronously as both are not dependent on each other but the HTML structure is like that.

Following is the HTML example:

```
<div ng-controller="earnMoreController">
     <!--some html-->
     <ng-include src="'/app/views/Default/Index.html?v='+AppVersioning" ng-controller="defaultController"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give more details what do you mean 'asynchronously'?

Comment: my second controller load method executes after the first controller load completion. I want to load both at a time , not after each other.

Comment: If you need a custom initialization, then you have to use promises or a shared service. You cannot modify the way Angular runs the controllers.